# GIMP Script-Fu Drop Shadow on Text?

Tags: image-processing, gimp, script-fu

I'm trying to create a Script-Fu script that at one point adds a drop-shadow. I use the script-fu-drop-shadow function as seen below

```
(script-fu-drop-shadow image textDrawable 0 7 16 '(0 0 0) 1 FALSE)
```

It works on normal layers, but not text layers it seems like. I've tried to find a function that converts a text layer to a bitmap layer, but cannot seem to find one for script-fu. Normally in GIMP, you just goto the layer, right click, and click 'Discard Text Information'.

Does anyone know a function that can achieve turning a text layer into a normal bitmap layer? Or a series of steps? Or maybe someone just knows a better way of going about creating a drop shadow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, turns out that after trying a lot of different things that one of the arguments I wrote was at 1 when it was supposed to be 100. I guess that's what happens when you think alpha levels should be at 1.0 for 100%, and 0.0 for 0%, but in reality alpha levels should be 100 for 100%. Here's corrected code:

```
(script-fu-drop-shadow image newTextLayer 0 7 16 '(0 0 0) 100 FALSE)
```